# Jquery Appear plugin initializes after scroll to bottom of page

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Im trying to get a Jquery Appear plugin working but it only works when you scroll down a bit, then go back over the items you've scrolled across as if you need to initialize it first.

here is the appear plugin im using https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear

Here is a Jfiddle that shows what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/bWTbt/

Basically I need each P tag to fade in on window enter(the P's that show up on screen on browser load should be visible, not fade in, only fade in when scrolling brings new items into the window). So right now all the P tag's are shown until you view them all(scroll to the bottom). Then once you've done that the opacity animation works. However I need it to animate the first time, as you scroll down the page.

Also I really just need the P's to animate / fade in, theres no real reason to animate / fade out although thats not as important right now as getting it to fade in the first time you scroll down(I tried just taking the disappear function out but everything stops working if you do that). Thanks!!

code as in bottom of JS in the JFiddle:

```
$('.ribbit p').appear(); 
$('.ribbit p').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
});
$('.ribbit p').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
  // this element is now outside browser viewport
  $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I just got it to fade in the first time, by animating the opacity to 0 on doc load but it makes all of them disappear. I guess what I really need is a proper function to check which P's are not in-screen and fade them out...?

Comment: Seem to have gotten it working by being able to make the content below the screen 0 opacity with the jquery viewport plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have gotten it working by setting the opacity for the css below-the-fold to 0 first. Did this using the below-the-fold selector offered by the viewport jquery plugin! yay